# Use C# Controller to get data from API

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, httprequest, http-get

I have an API which would return data using this format:

```
http://etr.azurewebsites.net/api/calculation/calculation?currency=eur&edition=standart&systems=50&version=5
```

I want to create an `HttpActionResult` which looks lie below:

```
public class CalculateController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: Calculate
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult CalculatePrice([FromUri]string currency,
                                                [FromUri]string edition = null,
                                                [FromUri]int? systems = null,
                                                [FromUri]string version = null)
        {

            //Code here

        }
    }
```

My `RouteConfig` class looks like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Also the Controller from where i get the data looks like this:

```
public class CalculationController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Calculate(.._parameters_..)
    {
        //Code here...
    }
}
```

How could i make a request to get the data from the URL i want?

Comment: basepath/api/Calculation/Calculate?param=values

Comment: Why do you need to go via API calls, if you have access to both the Calculation Logic and Calculate logic/Code, are the in the same solution?

Comment: No they are not in the same solution, they are in different ones. @PreetSingh

Comment: But you got access to the code how about a common Library. Trying to save a network call

Comment: @PreetSingh i suggested the same but i got as response that i should be getting data using a Request

Comment: what hinders you to add this api as a reference?

Comment: @etr ok well then the answer below is fine, also suppose you have a front end app, and if you do why not make 2 different ajax calls via JS rather than c#. but anyhow answer below is good to go.

Comment: Yes followed that suggestion and my issue got solved. Thanks @PreetSingh :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Httpclient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) to make a request to the url you wanted to call with the right parameters. I guess the url that you want to call is a web api/ RESTful web service.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    // New code:
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("Your API URL");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

Based on the type of API method ( GET/ POST ) you will make the appropriate call.
You can find more information in this sample.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

the sample has a console application as a client to make call the web api whereas in your case your MVC application is the client.

Comment: Glad that it helped.